Изменить в модели Django значение default
Хочу что бы при создании нового вопроса в тексте, значение num_question изменялось, в модели теста я устанавливаю кол-во вопросов, например в тесте 5 вопросов , создал первый вопрос з num_question == 1, а уже при создании второго num_question был уже дефолтно 2( что бы не выбирать каждый раз) . Так вот, я так понимаю что это пишется во вьюсах , если что добавлю код class CreateQuestionView
class Question(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, verbose_name="Тест", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='questions')
    question_text = models.TextField("Вопрос:")
    num_question = models.IntegerField("Номер вопроса:", default=1)


В Django есть специальное поле, которое автоматически увеличивается. Попробуйте прописать так:
num_question = models.AutoField("Номер вопроса:",primary_key=False, default=1)

Также, если мы не хотим чтобы у пользователя не было возможности его изменять, то добавляем параметр editable = False
